# Убрать рамки и системные кнопки окна в vba

Tags: winapi, vba

Подскажите плиз как убрать рамки и системные кнопки окна в vba, что-то наподобие BorderStyle = none в Delphi, наверное как то через Api это можно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете Visual Studio, то в окошке свойств формы (обычно оно справа снизу), ищите ControlBox и FormBorderSize, первое ставьте False, а второе None

Comment: vba, всмысле встроенный редактор в ms office

Comment: Тогда не представляю, оффисом почти не пользуюсь, предполагаю, что тогда ни как, VBA слишком упрощщённый язык.